# Strange BAD_ACCESS exception iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I have a property (noARC)

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *itemUUID;
```

and an initialization

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (_itemUUID) {
        [self updateViews];
    } else {
       _itemUUID = [[EADataManager sharedInstance] generateUuidString];
        NSLog(@"%@", _itemUUID);
    }
}
```

The UUID generation method is

```
- (NSString *)generateUuidString
{
    CFUUIDRef UUID = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    NSString *uuidString = (NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, UUID);
    [uuidString autorelease];
    CFRelease(UUID);
    return uuidString;
}
```

and I try to use this property in a very simple way in another method:

```
- (IBAction)submitButton:(id)sender
{
    if ([nameField.text length] > 3)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", _itemUUID);
        NSDictionary *changedData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nameField.text, priceField.text, quantityField.text, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Name", @"Price", @"Quantity", @"UUID", nil]];
    }
}
```

So on the second `NSLog` there is an exception `BAD_ACCESS`. Can't understand my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using ARC, this

```
_itemUUID = [[EADataManager sharedInstance] generateUuidString];
```

is wrong, it assigns an object you do not own to an instance variable.  That object will go away when the autorelease pool is drained.  Since you have declared a property, you should use it.

```
[self setItemUUID: [[EADataManager sharedInstance] generateUuidString]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `generateUuidString` is returning an `autorelease` value, so your `viewDidAppear` should retain it (which you can do by using the setter, `self.itemUUID = ...`).

And kambala is correct as well, that you've also added three objects for your four keys of your dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add your UUID to the object list in the dictionary, so number of objects and keys mismatches. Correct dictionary initialization:

```
NSDictionary *changedData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nameField.text, priceField.text, quantityField.text, _itemUUID, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Name", @"Price", @"Quantity", @"UUID", nil]];
```

Comment: This is true, but the cause of the error in the question is the unretained assignment to _itemUUID

Comment: @JeremyP True. But I wouldn't be surprised if ShurupuS put in that `NSLog` statement because the `NSDictionary` call was failing. And that's failing for the reason that kambala points out, not for `autorelease` reasons. Bottom line, both issues have to be fixed.